# CLLocationManager keeps generating EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cllocationmanager

In my view controller there is a `MKMapView` that centers on the user's current location.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let map : MKMapView! = MKMapView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    map.delegate = self
    map.showsUserLocation = true

    var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    region.center.latitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
    region.center.longitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
    region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2)
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)       
}
```

The issue is, whenever I run this program on an iOS simulator, it would crash at this line:

```
region.center.latitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
```

and generate `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` error. However, it works just fine when I ran it on my iPhone. I've set the Deployment target to iOS 8.0. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I managed to resolve the issue by simply changing the region.center setting code to

```
region.center.latitude = locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
region.center.longitude = locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your simulator there is no location object in locationManager instance. I recommend you to check the optional value and see if the value is not nil.

```
NSLog("\(locationManager.location?)")
```